# Using PHP to read a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I've created an html form that works fine by itself. However I also created a file called SignUp.php. I'm trying to use the code there in my html form but when I call the php it doesn't seem to read it.

Does the PHP form have to be in a seperate php file?

I attached one part of the html form

```
        <form method="post" action= "SignUp.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Your Name: </label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" value="<?php  echo $_POST['name'];?>"/>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Your Email: </label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Comment: </label>

                        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control"><?php echo $_POST['comment'];?></textarea>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id = "SignUp.php"/>

        </form>
```

PHP:

```
  ?php
 if ($_POST["submit"]) {
$error = "";
$result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Form submitted</div>';
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $error .= "<br/>Please enter your name!";
}
if (!$_POST['email']) {
    $error .= "<br/>Please enter your email!";
}
if (!$_POST['comment']) {
    $error .= "<br/>Please enter a comment!";
}
if ($_POST['email'] AND !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error .= "<br/> Please enter a valid email address";
}
if ($error) {
    $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form: </strong>' . $error . '</div>';
} else {
    $receiver = "sreeharsha11@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Comment from website!";
    $body =
    "Name: " . $_POST['name'] .
    "\nFrom: " . $_POST['email'] .
    "\nComment: " . $_POST['comment'];
    $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'];
    if (mail($receiver, $subject, $body, $headers) == 1) {
        $result = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Thank you! </strong>I'll be in touch.</div>";
    } else {
        $result = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</strong></div>";
    }
}
 }
  ?>
```

It just puts the call in the form.[image]

Comment: as we see raw php in the form i would guess this page is not *.php?

Comment: Your form needs to be a `.php` file... I'm guessing it's currently a `.html` file.

Comment: You described what you're getting now, you need to also be clear on what different behavior you're looking for.  What are you trying to change?

Comment: The PhP part is in a separate SignUp.php file. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not sure how to link that file to my html file where I actually make the form. I Tried "include but it didn't do anything".

Comment: `<form action="SignUp.php" ...` ??

Comment: I already put that in the form this div is in<form method="post" action= "SignUp.php">

Comment: can you add the full form

Comment: and after posting the form and you arrive on "SignUp.php' what exactly do you see ?

Comment: _“The PhP part is in a separate SignUp.php file”_ – your form contains PHP code as well (inside the input field values) – and so, to get that executed, your file that contains the form must be a .php file as well.

Comment: @CBroe I see. I can't run a php file the same way I run a html file right? I assume I need to use a web server? Perhaps you could recommend me one?

Comment: Go look up XAMPP, it’s an easy way to get started in setting up a local development environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The page with the php code on it needs to be a PHP file.

Your form page is displaying the php code, so I'm assuming you're probably trying to use php code on an HTML page, which won't really work. Change your form page to a .php file and this should fix your issue.

Comment: The PhP part is in a separate SignUp.php file. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not sure how to link that file to my html file where I actually make the form. I Tried "include but it didn't do anything".

Comment: How do you know it's not a php file?

Comment: you have to use a script include since your code is on an html page if I understand you correctly.
Try putting this where you want your php form (make sure the path to the signup.php file is correct):

<div id="form-include"></div>
<script>
$("#form-include").load("SignUp.php");
</script>